# Typescript using optional chanining (?.) in inequality

Tags: typescript

I thought it was possible to use optional chaining (`?.` operator) in inequalities, however I am getting a Typescript error saying my variable may be undefined.

I tried out the code below in an online [TypeScript Plaground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM7IDeAUMmcgLZwAeAEhMAOYAWYA-AFzIgCuFARtADcxAL7FiMHiARZcyRhDABlYAC8IARgAUAd2AATMMy68B0ADTJsmHPi4Y5+AJRFS5BLjxhkzBix8AXmR9I2ZkACpkACYRcmRgGGRtPyZWZAA+a1svNgA6Kjp-VldCMgB6cuQAHgBaeuQAEWwIPBAAch9dbCgAa3d4sk98HxAIXQB1Q2NkYJsnPAKaejSfKtiBwaglHigQZABtMcnp5itUgIBdOPJxTe2wXf2D0ONz4rBrsQkpGScFJSqDTRPSnUx8QRQKzzOx4Bw5FxueLDby+D6zEKnSIxG5kRLJGFeJZFVbIABkZLRpKyhPwxJWAVKFSqdVqyAmPV6eE2yK8o3GUzCGNpi0KDPS61xWx2e0Ox0FbypVyld3iDyeh1eZyVrC+oiAA), so I can see that the compiled code of `getSize1()` and `getSize2()` are different, but I don't totally understand why.

```js
interface Options {
    maxHeight?: number;
}

function getSize1(width: number, options: Options) {
    const height = width * 2;
    if (height > options?.maxHeight) {  // <-- Doesn't work
        const newWidth = options.maxHeight / 2;
        return [newWidth, height];
    }

    return [width, height];
}

function getSize2(width: number, options: Options) {
    const height = width * 2;
    if (options.maxHeight && height > options.maxHeight) {  // <-- Works
        const newWidth = options.maxHeight / 2;
        return [newWidth, height];
    }

    return [width, height];
}
```

Why is the `if` statement in `getSize1()` different than in `getSize2()`? Is there a shorthand syntax for `getSize2()`?

Comment: After writing my answer I just noticed: `options.maxHeight` and `options?.maxHeight` have the same type `number | undefined`. You would use the optional chaining for the case that `options` can be undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional chaining operator checks if the object you're trying to access is null or undefined, not the property.

This would be useful if `options` were an optional argument.

```
function getSize1(width: number, options?: Options)
```

To check if the property is undefined you have two options.

Explicitly checking against undefined:

```js
if (options.maxHeight !== undefined && height > options.maxHeight)
```

Checking against all `falsy` values, which will include `0` as invalid:

```js
if (options.maxHeight && height > options.maxHeight)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the `options?.maxHeight` has the same type as `options.maxHeight`: `number | undefined` (as it possibly is undefined). Therefore you are comparing the types `number > number | undefined`, but typescript does not allow `number > undefined` (what should `2 > undefined` mean?). Therefore this errors.

In the second case `options.maxHeight && height > options.maxHeight`, the comparison is done on the types `number > number` because it is already clear that it exists.